# How can I customize the look of vertices in Azure CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, data-visualization, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm currently working with CosmosDB and I want to personalize the look of my vertices. In the Data Explorer there a menu in the upper toolbar called "Style". The uppermost dropdown called "Show vertex (node) as" dropdown does work, it re-labels the vertices as expected, but no matter which option I choose in the "Map this property to node color" dropdown no colors change, and the "Map this property to node icon" dropdown doesn't work either.

The latter writes "Icon set: blank for this collection" but I can't really find anything else. Is there an option to change vertex colors or to use different icons? I don't find the corresponding documentation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing vertices color does work in my side, you may check if the property you selected   shares the same value with all the vertices.

[image]
[image]

While setting vertices icon, there's really no document related, [here's a vote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/34396504-document-how-to-make-use-icon-sets-in-the-graph).

I think you can use other tools to personalize the look. [Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-visualization) recommends some tools(Linkurious Enterprise, Cambridge Intelligence) which are recommended by Apache Tinkerpop community too.

> You can visualize data stored in Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API by using
> various data visualization solutions. The following solutions are
> recommended by the Apache Tinkerpop community for graph data
> visualization.